# register the dll successfully , but in regedit table there is nothing changed

Tags: c++, dll, filter

a dll that register a virtual camera,  when use the commond "regsvr32 xxx.dll " in cmd with administrator privileges, it will success that i can see the change in the regedit table;
but when i use the code,  it return true, but nothing changed .

```
BOOL RegisterFilter(const char* inFilterAx)
{
    typedef void (WINAPI * REGISTER_FUNC)(void);
    REGISTER_FUNC MyFunc = NULL;
    HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibrary(inFilterAx);
    int ret = 0;

    if (!hModule)
    {
        ret = GetLastError();
    }

    if (hModule)
    {
        MyFunc = (REGISTER_FUNC)GetProcAddress(hModule, "DllRegisterServer");
        BOOL pass = (MyFunc != NULL);
        if (pass)
        {
            MyFunc();
        }
        ::FreeLibrary(hModule);
        return pass;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you run this code with administrator privileges as well?

Comment: [`DllRegisterServer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/olectl/nf-olectl-dllregisterserver) returns an `HRESULT`, not `void`. Fix your declaration, and then see if the DLL is returning success or failure. If it returns success, then chances are the DLL ends up writing to the [VirtualStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry-virtualization) when not run with admin rights.